# How to get first element from Any

Tags: json, scala

My Json is a list of objects. I want to get the first one, but `Any` is making it difficult:

```
scala> import scala.util.parsing.json._
import scala.util.parsing.json._

scala> val str ="""
     | [
     |   {
     |     "UserName": "user1",
     |     "Tags": "one, two, three"
     |   },
     |   {
     |     "UserName": "user2",
     |     "Tags": "one, two, three"
     |   }
     | ]""".stripMargin
str: String =
"
 [
   {
     "UserName": "user1",
     "Tags": "one, two, three"
   },
   {
     "UserName": "user2",
     "Tags": "one, two, three"
   }
 ]"

scala> val parsed = JSON.parseFull(str)
parsed: Option[Any] = Some(List(Map(UserName -> user1, Tags -> one, two, three), Map(UserName -> user2, Tags -> one, two, three)))

scala> parsed.getOrElse(0)
res0: Any = List(Map(UserName -> user1, Tags -> one, two, three), Map(UserName -> user2, Tags -> one, two, three))

scala> parsed.getOrElse(0)(0)
<console>:13: error: Any does not take parameters
              parsed.getOrElse(0)(0)
```

How do I get the first element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pattern match the result(`Option[Any]`) to `List[Map[String, String]]`.

**1) Patter match example,**

```
scala> val parsed = JSON.parseFull("""[{"UserName":"user1","Tags":"one, two, three"},{"UserName":"user2","Tags":"one, two, three"}]""")

scala> parsed.map(users => users match { case  usersList : List[Map[String, String]] => usersList(0) case _ => Option.empty })
res8: Option[Equals] = Some(Map(UserName -> user1, Tags -> one, two, three))
```

**better pattern match,**

```
scala> parsed.map(_ match { case  head :: tail => head case _ => Option.empty })
res13: Option[Any] = Some(Map(UserName -> user1, Tags -> one, two, three))
```

2) Or else **you can cast the result (`Option[Any]`) but not recommended(as cast might throw ClassCastException),**

```
scala> parsed.map(_.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]](0))
res10: Option[Map[String,String]] = Some(Map(UserName -> user1, Tags -> one, two, three))
```